# Wordpress on Elasticbeanstalk with RDS and EFS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am trying to deploy an Wordpress application on top of ElasticBeanstalk with EFS and RDS attaching to it.

I am using EFS is for storing Wordpress files.

Configured Elastic beanstalk with auto-scaling. When we are terminating existing instance, auto-scaling should create another application with all properties set like.. RDS and EFS connection details.

But When new application is launched by auto-scaling, it is not retrieving RDS, EFS and other properties that were set initially. New application is prompting for setting again for DB and other setting.

How to make these persistent when additional application is launched in Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create [custom AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html) with pre-configured wordpress setup. Then in your ASG you are going to use the AMI. This way, the new instances will launch will RDS, EFS and other properties per-configured.